# Dockerfile build on Google Cloud Build not printing test logs

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I have a simple **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "test"]
```

I run it inside **Google Cloud Build** and get the following logs:

```
...
Removing intermediate container 19ae183b28c6
 ---> 5802f218fa4e
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> a1600834b6e0
Step 6/6 : CMD npm run test
 ---> Running in bfb7be511b96
Removing intermediate container bfb7be511b96
 ---> 6e974d117670
Successfully built 6e974d117670
...
```

At step `6/6`, `npm run test`, I am not seeing the logs that I would on my local machine:

`npm run test`:

```
 PASS  __tests__/order.spec.ts
 PASS  __tests__/news.spec.ts
 PASS  __tests__/product.spec.ts (5.328s)
 PASS  __tests__/review.spec.ts
 PASS  __tests__/donation.spec.ts
 PASS  __tests__/referral.spec.ts
 PASS  __tests__/nonprofit.spec.ts

Test Suites: 7 passed, 7 total
Tests:       22 passed, 22 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.291s, estimated 9s
```

**How can I get these logs to show up in the build logs?**

Comment: You're building a container image that, when run, will run `npm run test`. Cloud Build just does the build. It does not `docker run` the image. If you replace `CMD ["npm","run","test"]` with `RUN npm run test` your build will include the `npm run test` and it *should* do what you ask. Though you're then also creating a container image that does nothing when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are building the image not running it :). When you run the container you will see the logs printing out e.g

`docker run -it my-image`

Comment: Thank you, is there way to do this automatically on `google-cloud-project`? I got to work locally.

Comment: take a look at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) you can build and run images by specifying instructions in docker-compose file.